# Get Last 20 Rows of Inner Join When Sorted ASC

Tags: mysql, database

Question title pretty much sums it up.

I'm joining two tables with the results ordered by a timestamp column, & sorted in ascending order (so the most recent rows are at the bottom). How do I get the last 20 rows in this case?

Code (Assume the two tables are Table A & Table B):

```
SELECT A.*, B.some_column
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id AND (other conditions here)
                ORDER BY A.timestamp ASC
                LIMIT 20
```

This currently returns the first 20 rows. I need the last 20.

P.S. I need the final result set to be sorted in ASCENDING order. The most recent rows need to be at the end, not the beginning!

Comment: show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT A.*, B.some_column
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id AND (other conditions here)
                ORDER BY A.timestamp DESC
                LIMIT 20

    ) AS RESULT

    ORDER BY RESULT.timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order it by ASC in the query you could:

```
SELECT A.*, B.some_column
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
                WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM (
                 SELECT id FROM A ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
                ) AS s) ORDER BY A.timestamp ASC
```

Comment: @MachOSX yeah I realized it pretty soon and changed it. had some problems with the update so it turned blank for a while...this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT A.*, B.some_column
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id AND (other conditions here)
                ORDER BY A.timestamp Desc
                LIMIT 20
) Temp
ORDER BY A.timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order of the result, and

In SQL server, use:

```
select top 20 ...
```

In MySQL, use:

```
select ... order by num desc limit 20
```

Comment: The end result needs to be resorted ASC

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the other way:

```
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: The end result needs to be resorted ASC